# Regex in Go: How to replace only the capture group?

Tags: regex, go

I want to capture a substring within a string by identifying characters around, and replace only the captured substring, without the surrounding characters.

This is what I tried:

```
func main() {
    regex, _ := regexp.Compile("://(.*:.*)@")
    maskedValue := regex.ReplaceAllString("http://user:pass@domain.com/path", "****")
    fmt.Println(maskedValue)
}
```

The output is:

`http****domain.com/path`

I need the output to be:

`http://****@domain.com/path`

I tried to create a capture group, thinking that `ReplaceAllString` will only replace it, by sadly this doesn't work

Comment: See https://go.dev/play/p/C2mjO8EXSPJ

Comment: `"://****@"` ? (there is a 15 char limit to a comment)